# How to convert string to real array laravel

Tags: php, file, laravel, amazon-s3

I have the following string in my variable which is grabbed from my s3 bucket content,I need to return this as real array in my function.

How can I process this in Laravel?

```
<?php
return array(
    "accepted" => "The :attribute must be accepted.",
    "active_url" => "The :attribute is not a valid URL.",
    "after" => "The :attribute must be a date after :date.",
    "alpha" => "The :attribute may only contain letters.",
    "alpha_dash" => "The :attribute may only contain letters, numbers, and dashes.",
    "alpha_num" => "The :attribute may only contain letters and numbers.",
    "before" => "The :attribute must be a date before :date.",
)
```

Comment: can you clarify by providing the 'string', what you have there is an array. what is your definition of a 'real' array?

Comment: My real same the array that I have given,I read my stored php files from s3 bucket,Its give the string of my php file ,not the real php content.So I need to convert this string to a real php array.

Comment: You have valid associative array. there is nothing like "real array" in PHP. I am not seeing any php content in your given array. it is just keys and values

Comment: I think he wants to load a php file that's stored somewhere else. That php file returns an array (like Laravel's config files).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my problem I have defined that I need to access my arrays from sting,In my variable I have this sting,I use php eval function to return the array from this sting.Thanks all who contribute help my self.

```
 $results = eval("?>$string");
```

now I can execute the string.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
$array = include('path_to_your_file');
dd($array);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.My problem is not to load the files,I have the content of the files in variable,contents are same as php file,but it not returning the array as php.How can access the array,either converting to a new array or else any techniques .

Comment: @nizar You said you were "grabbing" the file. I think this solution works if you are storing the "grabbed" file somewhere in your filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

You have valid associative array and it is "real".

I assume that, you have created a function and you have returned an array.

```
function test(){
  return array(
      "accepted" => "The :attribute must be accepted.",
      "active_url" => "The :attribute is not a valid URL.",
      "after" => "The :attribute must be a date after :date.",
      "alpha" => "The :attribute may only contain letters.",
      "alpha_dash" => "The :attribute may only contain letters, numbers, and dashes.",
      "alpha_num" => "The :attribute may only contain letters and numbers.",
      "before" => "The :attribute must be a date before :date.",
  );
}

$data = test();
echo '<pre>'; print_r($data);
```

You can access particulary key by,

```
echo $data['accepted'];  // The :attribute must be accepted.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should try `serialize` and `unserialize`

```
$arr = [ 'key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2', 'key3' => 'value3' ];
$serializedArr = serialize($arr);
$newArr = unserialize($serializedArr);
print_r($newArr);
```